# How to display the name in an array containg name=>value pair

Tags: yii

I'm new to yii framework. I have created a simple dropdownlist.

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'max_cost', array('2'=>'Yes', '0'=>'No'), 
                                  array(
                                          'empty'=>'Choose one', 
                                          'onchange'=>'alert(item.value);',
                                          )
                                  );
```

Now when I select Yes, the alert box will display Yes and when i select no the alert box will display no. 
Suppose I want to display 2 when I select yes and 0 when I select no . What should I do for this? item.value displays the RHS I want to display LHS

Comment: I tried alert(value), is it the right way to do it

Answer (score 1):

log the "item" and you will know what are exactly parameters bound to items, then you can alert it or whatever you need:

```
'onchange'=>'console.log(item);', // here you can see what's inside item
```